# make h2 text underline when hovering over image

Tags: html, css, alignment

jsfiddle.net/pxojrb1o/

Hello,

I'm trying to make the 'retro products' text underline when you hover over the green picture. If I put the green picture in the h2 tag, it misaligns. can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML: I added a class to the h2

```
<h2 class="products"><a href="products.html">retro products</a></h2>
```

The CSS

```
.home-featured-class:hover .products {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxojrb1o/3/

For more information see this thread: [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)